# How can change a MYSQL Join Query in Linq Methods

Tags: c#, .net-core, linq-to-sql

I write a MySql join code, and want to retrive same value from the Dotnetcore linq methods.

My Join code is below:

```sql
  SELECT GL.Id  AS GradeLevels,
         CRS.Name AS CourseName,
         GL.Title AS GradlevelName,
         AVG (ASTSTU.ObtainedMarks)
    FROM GradeLevels GL
         INNER JOIN Courses AS CRS ON CRS.GradeLevelsID = GL.Id
         INNER JOIN Units AS UNT ON UNT.CourseID = CRS.ID
         INNER JOIN Lessons AS LSN ON LSN.UnitsId = UNT.Id
         INNER JOIN Assignments AS AST ON AST.LessonId = LSN.id
         INNER JOIN AssignmentStudents AS ASTSTU ON ASTSTU.AssignmentId = AST.id
   WHERE CRS.SchoolSystemsID = "08d6a1f2-26df-4ad5-25d3-2a26960aa3fd" -- School System id.
GROUP BY GL.Id;
```

Now I want to change above MySQL Join into Dotnet core linq method  to create an API that will be Showing, I try to write code for this

```
public async Task<ICollection<GradeLevels>> GetSchoolSystemGradLevelsAverage(Guid schoolSystemId)
{
    List<GradeLevels> dashboadOverAllAverage = new List<GradeLevels>();

    var dashboadOverAllAverage1 = await _GpsContext.GradeLevels
        .Include(d=>d.Departments)
        .ThenInclude(c=>c.Courses.Where(s=>s.SchoolSystemsID ==schoolSystemId))
        .ThenInclude(u=>u.Units)
        .ThenInclude(l=>l.Lessons)
        .ThenInclude(a=>a.Assignment)
        .ThenInclude(a=>a.assignmentStudents)
        .GroupBy(g=>g.ID)
        .ToListAsync();
    return dashboadOverAllAverage;
}
```

Now I want to show the data though API and want to call  to fields GradeLvels name and Average Marks.

```
[HttpGet()]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCEOGradeLevelAverage(string schoolSystemId)
{
    var overallgradeAverages = await _ceoDashboadRepository.GetSchoolSystemGradLevelsAverage(Guid.Parse(schoolSystemId));
    List<GetGradeLevelAverageVm> getOverallAverageVms = new List<GetGradeLevelAverageVm>();

    foreach (GradeLevels overallgradeAverage in overallgradeAverages)
    {
        getOverallAverageVms.Add(new GetGradeLevelAverageVm
        {
            Marks = overallgradeAverage.Id.ToString(), //Want to show lable of AvrageMark
            Name = overallgradeAverage.Name //Want to show Gradelevel name
        });
    }
    return Ok(getOverallAverageVms);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do select too much from your DB. Here an example, how to select the nessecary values:

```
using (TestDbContext ctx = new TestDbContext())
{
    var tmp = ctx.AssignmentStudents
        .Include(s => s.Assignment) // Include all Childs..
        .ThenInclude(a => a.Lesson)
        .ThenInclude(l => l.Unit)
        .ThenInclude(u => u.Course)
        .ThenInclude(c => c.GradeLevel)
        .Where(a => a.LessonId == 123)
        .GroupBy(g => // Group by your Key-Values Grade and Course (You could take names instead of ids. Just for simplification)
        new
        {
            GradeLevel = g.Assignment.Lesson.Unit.Course.GradeLevel.Id,
            Course = g.Assignment.Lesson.Unit.Course.Id
        })
        .Select(s => // Select the result into an anonymous type
        new
        {
            GradeLevels = s.Key.GradeLevel, // with same keys like grouping
            Course = s.Key.Course,
            AverageObtainedMarks = s.Average(a => a.ObtainedMarks) // and an average ObtainedMarks from objects matching the key
        })
        .Where(s => s.GradeLevel == 1);

    foreach (var t in tmp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.GradeLevels + " " + t.Course + ": " + t.AverageObtainedMarks);
    }
}
```

Here a the classes and dbcontext I used:

```
public class GradeLevel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GradeLevelId { get; set; }
    public GradeLevel GradeLevel { get; set; }
    public List<Unit> Units { get; set; }
}
public class Unit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public List<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
}
public class Lesson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public Unit Unit { get; set; }
    public List<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }
}
public class Assignment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LessonId { get; set; }
    public Lesson Lesson { get; set; }
    public List<AssignmentStudent> AssignmentStudents { get; set; }

}
public class AssignmentStudent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AssignmentId { get; set; }
    public Assignment Assignment { get; set; }
    public decimal ObtainedMarks { get; set; }
}

public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AssignmentStudent> AssignmentStudents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Unit> Units { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GradeLevel> GradeLevels { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have already same dbcontext, what i doing that i have Join(in mysql) to retrieve the data, I want to convert all the join in Linq Method to create API in dotnet core.

Comment: The DbContext and Data-Classes are for testing. The upper example shows how to Join the Tables (include properties)m Group them correctly and select the fields you need.

Comment: How Add where condition in the given example, like in the Join mention, the 'SchoolSystemId' will be a fields in the Course table.

Comment: @VipinJha Where ever you want. Before or after the grouping. I did add two `Where`-conditions to the example.